# 500 error after pushing to heroku - DEBUG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, open-uri

Im having an openuri issue when in production. The code below works in development but when in production the unauthorized error comes up. The only way i've solved this is if i put the api key directly in the url, which obviously i dont want to do. Any ideas why my current code doesnt work?

```html
 api_key = ENV["NEWS_API"]
 url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=#{api_key}"
 article_serialized = open(url).read
@articles = JSON.parse(article_serialized)
```

```html
2018-10-25T01:55:47.184856+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-10-25T01:55:47.184804 #4] FATAL -- : [40a7ee38-ef6e-4622-ad86-edb34d7eeccf] OpenURI::HTTPError (401 Unauthorized):
```

```html
Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ twittter-clone... up, run.6483 (Free)
D, [2018-10-25T01:12:44.387465 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(2661719123600558280)
D, [2018-10-25T01:12:44.433095 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
D, [2018-10-25T01:12:44.456835 #4] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (3.8ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-10-25T01:12:44.480937 #4] DEBUG -- :    (5.3ms)  BEGIN
D, [2018-10-25T01:12:44.485057 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.7ms)  COMMIT
D, [2018-10-25T01:12:44.492822 #4] DEBUG -- :    (7.1ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(2661719123600558280)
```

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs (in this case, run `heroku logs`) for more detail. You can [edit] your question and add what you find there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenURI returns a 401 error and my guess is that the `ENV['NEWS_API']` is not set. You can run `heroku config` in the terminal or look it up on the web interface: `Settings` -> `Reveal Config Vars`